# Function to return list and then clear

Tags: python, python-3.x

how could I make my function clear the list and return the inital list on the first execution, and then display a empty list on the second run? I have tried using.
Kind regards

```
def remove():
    items = ["car", "plane", "bus"]
    if len(items) != 0:
        
        return items and items.clear()
    
    
print(remove())
print(remove())
```

```
First Print expected output: ["car", "plane", "bus"]
Second Print expected output: []
```

Comment: make a global param called `run_times` which is `0` and every time u execute function, you add 1 to it. Put `run_times += 1`  in function.

Comment: This is not directly possible as items is defined every time the function runs. Also the `None` is due to `items and items.clear()` outputting the result of `items.clear()` which is `None`.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is not directly possible as `items` is defined every time the function runs.

Also the `None` in your output is due to `items and items.clear()` giving the result of `items.clear()` which is `None`.

What might come closest to what you want would be:

```
# define "items" as a main scope variable
items = ["car", "plane", "bus"]

def remove(items=items):  # or remove(items=["car", "plane", "bus"])
    output = items.copy() # make a copy as items.clear() will clear the object
    items.clear()
    return output
    
print(remove())
print(remove())
```

output:

```
['car', 'plane', 'bus']
[]
```

But honestly, I don't see a good use case for it…

Comment: @mozay I guess second list should be empty?...Here we are getting `None`

Comment: @Bhargav you're right, for some reason I thought OP wanted None (as in their original code `if len(items) != 0` would only return something when the list is not empty), it makes it even easier to return an empty list, see update

Comment: The keyword argument isn't needed (and makes no sense as an API).

Comment: @ekhumoro right, but I just thought it would be easier to break down the logic (I also added a comment for that)

Comment: I don't see that you've explained it at all. The choices should be: (1) global and no arguments; or (2) no global and keyword default. But what are the advantages of (2)? It seems like an unnecessary hack with the *disadvantage* that it creates an API with no meaningful purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the fact that argument defaults are only created once:

```
def remove(items = ["car", "plane", "bus"]):
    rv = items.copy()
    items.clear()
    return rv

print(remove())
print(remove())
```

If you want to avoid the extra steps if list is already empty, you can adjust:

```
def remove(items = ["car", "plane", "bus"]):
    if items:
        rv = items.copy()
        items.clear()
        return rv
    else:
        return items
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the list outside the function, and declare it in the function as a global variable to modify it.

```
items = ["car", "plane", "bus"]

def remove():
    global items
    print(items)
    if len(items) != 0:
        items.clear()
        return() 
    
    
remove()
remove()
```

Comment: No need for `global items`, since you are not assigning to it. And `return()` doesn’t really make sense, and probably does not do what you think it does. At any rate, OP wants the function to return the list.